# Sequelize: Ordering query results by function

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I am trying to order the results of a findAll call in Sequelize. I am trying to use code similar to:

```
myModel.findAll({
    ...
    order: [
        [sequelize.fn('myOrderFunction', sequelize.col('col1'), sequelize.col('col2'), 'ASC'],
    ]
    ...
});
```

to get the results of the query and order them by the result of 'myOrderFunction', which is a function which takes the values of the two columns and returns a number. All I want to do is order the results of the query in ascending order of value of the function.

Comment: So your resulting query would be something like `SELECT ... ORDER BY (SELECT * FROM myOrderFunction(col1, col2))`?

Comment: What SQL does your existing code generate?

Comment: @joshua.paling I gave up trying to do it sequelize's way and just used raw queries